# Modeling data with classes

Tags: c#, arrays, class-design

I am fairly new to programming and I am having difficulty in modeling the following code of program.

The program reads a file, selects certain requirements, and displays them. Have tried to use passing arrays as arguments or functions as indicated in my textbook, but I can't seem to write it correctly into C#. Using examples such as int getAges(int array[], integer).

```
//Parsing data into memory

string content;
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(File.Open("Data.txt", FileMode.Open)))
{
    content = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
string[] rows = content.Split('\n'); //Each row is on a new line
string[][] table = new string[rows.Length][];
for (int i = 0; i < rows.Length; table[i] = rows[i].Split(','), i++) ;



//selecting information

int[] districts = new int[rows.Length];
int[] ages = new int[rows.Length];

for (int i = 0; i < rows.Length; i++)
{
    districts[i] = int.Parse(table[i][3]);
    ages[i] = int.Parse(table[i][0]);
}



//Analyzing selected information

foreach (int district in districts.Distinct().OrderBy(x => x))
    Console.WriteLine("District {0} has {1} resident(s)", district, districts.Count(x => x == district));
Console.WriteLine("Ages 0-18 : {0} resident(s)", ages.Count(x => x < 18));
Console.WriteLine("Ages 18-30 : {0} resident(s)", ages.Count(x => x >= 18 && x <= 30));
Console.WriteLine("Ages 31-45 : {0} resident(s)", ages.Count(x => x >= 31 && x <= 45));
Console.WriteLine("Ages 46-64 : {0} resident(s)", ages.Count(x => x >= 46 && x <= 64));
Console.WriteLine("Ages >=65 : {0} resident(s)", ages.Count(x => x >= 65));
```

Comment: What exactly do you expect to happen, and what *is* really happening instead? Any error messages? Any wrong output (*what* is wrong about it; how does it differ from what you expected)? Also, for clarification: Are you actually asking for anything related to "modules" or "modulation" of any kind, or about "modelling"?

Comment: Hello O.R. Mapper, I'm sorry for not being clearer. The program runs excellently. The question that I am asking is that even though it's an array program, is it possible for it to be separated into modules and then called from the main in order to execute the same way? (it's more of an aesthetic/better way to format the code in its entirety.) I am trying to do it as I've done for simple programs but it doesn't seem to work from previous programs/textbook in pseudo-code. Thanks for commenting.

Comment: @user2959027: can you show sample data of what your Data.txt file contains

Comment: Yes sure! actually I can just write a new line of info as it is supposed to be hypothetical census info.

Comment: 22, M, S, 24 would be a person, the Data.txt file contains a variety of this format. Thank you Sudhakar

Comment: Do you want to move logically related parts of this code do different blocks and call them?

Comment: @user2959027 what is a module? Are you asking if you could *model* it into classes? Yes if so.

Comment: Yes that would be correct, isn't that how all of modular programs are organized? As if let's say there is a program that asks for a total salary of a person, the program would be divided into the main which could have declaration of variables and maybe some Console.Writelines, while it calls for a module that performs the calculation, and another that displays the calculation. (This is how they've been teaching me it's supposed to be). In this program I'm trying to divide it into the main, the selection of info from the array, and the analyzing of info. (They are commented at the moment.)

Answer (score 3):

You can shorten the entire code to this using Linq.

```
var table = File.ReadLines("Data.txt").Select(x => x.Split(',')).ToArray();
```

Note that [File.ReadLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx) reads line lazily, so its a plus for memory efficiency as well (if you're doing something more with it). To get the districts and ages separately, I would do something like:

```
var districts = table.Select(x => int.Parse(x[3])).ToArray();
var ages = table.Select(x => int.Parse(x[0])).ToArray();
```

You can also write your `foreach` in one line as well with linq.

```
var districtFrequency = districts.GroupBy(x => x)
                                 .Select(x => new { name = x.Key, count = x.Count() })
                                 .OrderBy(x => x.name);

foreach (var district in districtFrequency)
    Console.WriteLine("District {0} has {1} resident(s)", district.name, districts.count);
```

---

I think I misread your question. You can model your logic into classes and access it the oop way, but without knowing your model/domain its pointless to detail anything. However here is a rough sketch:

```
public class Person //or whatever the entity is
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public int Age { get; private set; }
    public string Place { get; private set; }

    //provide a suitable constructor
}
```

Now you will be able to get a list of `Person` from your text file almost the same way:

```
public static IEnumerable<Person> GetPeople(string filepath)
{
    foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(filepath))
    {
        var properties = line.Split(',');
        yield return new Person(properties[0], int.Parse(properties[1]), etc...
        //according to properties of Person class
    }
}

//you can call it like
var people = GetPeople("Data.txt").ToList();

//your foreach calls will look almost the same:
foreach (var district in people.Select(x => x.Place).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x))
    Console.WriteLine("District {0} has {1} resident(s)", district, people.Count(x => x.Place == district));
Console.WriteLine("Ages 0-18 : {0} resident(s)", people.Count(x => x.Age < 18));
Console.WriteLine("Ages 18-30 : {0} resident(s)", people.Count(x => x.Age >= 18 && x.Age <= 30));
Console.WriteLine("Ages 31-45 : {0} resident(s)", people.Count(x => x.Age >= 31 && x.Age <= 45));
Console.WriteLine("Ages 46-64 : {0} resident(s)", people.Count(x => x.Age >= 46 && x.Age <= 64));
Console.WriteLine("Ages >=65 : {0} resident(s)", people.Count(x => x.Age >= 65));
```

You can create your own collection class and delegate these functionalities to the class itself but that may not be very useful.

```
public class People : List<Person>
{
    //your methods to fetch or print or whatever
}
```

---

Lastly, a text file is not the best way to do this kind of data storing mostly. You might want to look into dedicated databases.